# Is there a BSD Bitcoin client?

Tags: client, installation

I have a few BSD-based systems sitting around serving away, but for the most part they're idle CPU-wise. Does anyone knew of a bitcoin client that I could run on these machines to make them more productive while they wait for requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [standard Bitcoin client](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) should run on BSD machines. If you encounter any difficulties getting it to compile or run, ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

there is a port available for freeBSD: http://www.freshports.org/net-p2p/bitcoin/